# AngularJS NgMessages does not hide messages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS so this might be a pretty stupid question.

By using the [Angular documentation on ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) , I'd like to implement message boxes that are displayed when certain requirements are met.

However, even when using the copy-pasted example, the message boxes are not hidden even if their requirements are not met. The `$error` variable does show the correct values, though.

```js
angular.module('ngMessagesExample', ['ngMessages']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm">
    <label>
        Enter your name:
        <input type="text" name="myName" ng-model="name"  ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" required />
    </label>
    <pre>myForm.myName.$error = {{ myForm.myName.$error | json }}</pre>

    <ng-messages for="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:maroon;" role="alert">
        <ng-message when="required">You did not enter a field</ng-message>
        <ng-message when="minlength">Your field is too short</ng-message>
        <ng-message when="maxlength">Your field is too long</ng-message>
    </ng-messages>
</form>
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the alternate solution for your problem.

```
<p ng-if="myForm.myName.$error.minlength">Your field is too short.</p>   
<p ng-if="myForm.myName.$error.maxlength">Your field is too long.</p>   
<p ng-if="myForm.myName.$error.required">You did not enter a field.</p>
```

Comment: This is even better than getting the ngmessages problem to work (in my case)
Thank you so much!

Comment: How is that a good solution? The whole point of `ng-messages` is to avoid these long and ugly expressions inside `ng-if` or `ng-show`.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fine, seems to me you just needed to import ngMessages module separately. (Have you checked the console for errors?)

Keep in mind I moved the *script* tags to the bottom of the *body* tag for better performance, but it works fine in the header as well.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<form name="myForm">
  <label>
    Enter your name:
    <input type="text" name="myName" ng-model="name"  ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="20" required />
  </label>
  <pre>myForm.myName.$error = {{ myForm.myName.$error | json }}</pre>

  <ng-messages for="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:maroon;" role="alert">
    <ng-message when="required">You did not enter a field</ng-message>
    <ng-message when="minlength">Your field is too short</ng-message>
    <ng-message when="maxlength">Your field is too long</ng-message>
  </ng-messages>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.1/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mv0UuCoOwIGamnc42Hal)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried to readd the angular-messages.js but it did not change anything - however, I still learned something thanks to your reply!

Comment: I had the same problem and only the import of the ngMessages module was missing to work. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-if="myForm.myName.$touched" for="myName" ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:maroon;" role="alert">
        <ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</ng-message>
        <ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</ng-message>
        <ng-message="maxlength">Your field is too long</ng-message>
    </div>
```

Remove `when` from your code.

Comment: Unfortunately all messages are still displayed at once (as soon as the input has been touched)

Comment: I've also tried this by using  `<div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>` instead of the ng-messages (without `when`)
It seems to be the same (well one is a directive attribute and the other one an element, but still...)
Thank you for your reply